# Job failing during workload identity pool credental creation, "argument AUDIENCE: Must be specified."

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to authenticate my CI/CD runner into my GCP project using Workload Identity Federation. I have been following the official [example](https://gitlab.com/guided-explorations/gcp/configure-openid-connect-in-gcp/-/blob/main/.gitlab-ci.yml) from Gitlab, but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.iam.workload-identity-pools.create-cred-config) argument AUDIENCE: Must be specified.`

This is what my .gitlab.yml looks like:

```
stages:
  - login1
  - login2

gcp-auth:
  stage: login1
  image: google/cloud-sdk:slim
  script:
    - echo ${CI_JOB_JWT_V2} > .ci_job_jwt_file # CI_JOB_JWT_V2 is automatically generated with each job we run
    - gcloud iam workload-identity-pools create-cred-config ${GCP_WI_PROVIDER}
      --service-account="${GCP_WIF_SA_EMAIL}"
      --output-file=.gcp_temp_cred.json
      --credential-source-file=.ci_job_jwt_file
    - gcloud auth login --cred-file=`pwd`/.gcp_temp_cred.json
    - gcloud auth list
```

So from the documentation, the first augument which I pass to the command (in my case `${GCP_WI_PROVIDER}` should be the `AUDIENCE`, yet it keep failing.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The variables which I want to use are not yet defined in the project. Guess I need to bootstrap the project first